# Get string contents though attribute

Tags: python

What attribute is used by the `str` class to hold the actual contents of the string?

For example:

```
x = 'fruit'
print getattr(x, some_attribute) # Should print 'fruit'
getattr(x, some_attribute) == 'fruit' # Should be True
```

Comment: How would the logic go here? Because `x` has *no* attribute named `'someattributename'` it should just print `x` *itself*?

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, the questioner wants to know which internal attribute is used by the `str` class to hold the string contents.

Comment: Yes Tim, you got it right.

Comment: @Tim Wouldn't that be implemented directly in C?

Comment: @aIKid: I suspect so, but I'm not familiar enough with the implementation.

Comment: @Tim Me neither. So to really see the answer we will need to wait for someone that's _really_ familiar..

Comment: This is like "which of your pockets are you hiding yourself in", or "which room of my house is my house in". There's no such attribute. (If there were, what type would it even be but `str`?)

Comment: There is no 'attribute' on a `str` value that holds the actual value. The *object itself* is the value. You can call `.__str__()` on the value, but that method really just returns `self`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> x = 'fruit'
>>> getattr(x, '__str__')()
'fruit'
>>> getattr(x, '__str__')() == 'fruit'
True
```

Comment: This really is useful. But what I understand from the answers from you and others here is that string doesn't have any attribute which holds its value. We rather have to use `__str__` method to get it. Is that correct?

Comment: @gliese581g Yes, there's no attribute that actually stores the value, At least not for the built-in classes, `self` itself is the value.

Comment: @gliese581g: You don't have to use the `__str__` method. You can just use the string directly. All of these method calls simply get you exactly where you started.

Answer (score 2):

`x` doesn't have an attribute that contain its string. `x` itself is the string.

The following would suffice.

```
print x
```

Or here is a fancy way, calling the `__str__` function:

```
print x.__str__()
```

If you insist on using `getattr`:

```
print getattr(x, '__str__')()
```

But as others explained in the comment, this will only return `self`, which is the instance itself.

When you declared `x = 'fruit'` `x` now contains `'fruit'`, an instance of `str`. `x.someattribute` is the same as `'fruit'.someattribute`. In short, `'fruit'` doesn't have it's value (`'fruit'`) as an attribute. It's the value itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to do it using `getattr`.

Comment: @gliese581g: but **why** do you want to use `getattr()`?

Answer (score 0):

variable "x" contains 'fruit' so just :

```
print x
```